# I am unable to login to my GitHub account

Tags: github, deployment, github-api

[image]

One day, GitHub sent an email notifying me they forced a password reset. Then I followed the link to reset my password as my previous password didn't work again. To my surprise, every time I try to reset the password, I am unable to get an authentication code as SMS, it keeps saying I am not authorized to receive the OTP. I tried reaching out to their support every chance I got but no response.

Please note that my phone number works.

Thanks.

I tried recovering 2FA authentication and all but I never set it up.